# How to check header of request inside a method using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a method that will hit other API. And I made a condition to decide which auth token that will be used while posting to that API. Example:

```
class OrderFee
  def perform
    get_pricing
  end
  
  private

  def get_pricing
    payload = {
       from: "a",
       to: "b"
    }

    authorization = ''
    if Config.UsingFirstToken?
       authorization = "first_token"
    else
       authorization = "second_token"
    end

    response = Connection.MyCourier.post(url, payload) do |req|
       req.headers['Authorization'] = authorization
    end
    response.body
  end
end
```

I want to make 2 test case using Rspec to make sure if `Config.UsingFirstToken` true, it will hit the API using `first_token`, and otherwise. I can check the return value of this method, but I can't find a way to `expect` header from that POST action

Comment: As an aside: there is no need to initialize `authorization` as an empty String or to handle assignment in each conditional branch. (Both are generally considered code smell in Ruby) Instead you can assign `authorization` based on the return from the `if` itself e.g. `authorization = if Config.UsingFirstToken? #...` or even use a ternary `authorization = Config.UsingFirstToken? ? 'first_token' : 'second_token'`

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the request object in your spec.

Expect what the header equals like this:

`expect(request.headers['Authorization']).to eq("first_token")`

Or whatever you expect the token to be.